# how might one spoof geographic location on a desktop Mac

Tags: macos, geolocation

I use a social network site that attaches location information to posts made on iPhones or MacBooks. When I post from my desktop, no GPS information is available and this field is left blank (there is no provision for user-entered data, unfortunately). Is there some way to spoof GPS on a desktop Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Is this site web based? Or app based?

If this is a web based service one idea that *might work* is to change your user agent in your web browser. For example, in Safari there is `Develop` menu that you can activate via the `Advanced` tab under `Preferences`:

[image]

Once activated, go to to the `Develop` menu and choose the `User Agent` option. There is a nice preset list of common user agents. So in this case just change it to one of the mobile device options like `Safari iOS7 — iPhone`:

[image]

Now with that done, go to the site in question, login & see how the site reacts. Mind you this is simply a brainstorming idea of a tact to spoof a mobile device. For all you—or we—know the site in question does server based geolocation based on IP address or just reacts differently from a real mobile device. And if that is the case, chance are you are out of luck.

But the choice of how/when geolocation data is added to a site is really based on the site owner’s preference in most cases and not controllable by end user interaction.

Comment: A fine suggestion but one that, in this case, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Mountain Lion** comes with **Localization Services** which enables applications and websites to gather and use information regarding your current location. This location is determined using the information of your **local Wi-Fi network**.

To enable it just go to **System Preferences / Security & Privacy / Privacy** and check the *Enable Location Services* checkbox.

Applications to which you have granted the permission to use the Location Services will be shown in this panel. Each application will display, too, if it is turned on or off with a checkbox.

Under the **Safari** privacy preferences you can find different options for limiting websites access to the localization feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, "Enable Location Services" is grayed out and can not be turned on. This may be because I am using a Mac that does not have a wifi card; it is ethernet-only.

Comment: @MichaelStern unlock it first

Answer (score 0):

Many such sites do not rely on the client device to tell their location (as they tend to be web-based anyway, and there is no easy weay to tell a browser to reveal its location) - they will get the geo information from the IP address you are using to connect. In this case, the best way to spoof your location is to use a VPN/tunnel service that exists for this purpose.

These tunnels usually exist to give people access to services (such as Netflix, etc.) that require you to be in a certain country in order to function.